# How to read an encrypted database password from application.properties in a spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot

I have an application.properties file in a Spring boot application which has the db Url, username, password and few other properties. The password is in an encrypted form. I have the decryption logic in a java function. How can I decrypt the password before Spring boot creates a datasource.

Comment: Read values from properties file using Environment or by @Value and then pass that to your decrypting method/functions

Answer (score 3):

You can use @Value annotation

```
@Value("${mypassword}")
private String encryptedPass;
```

then you can call the decryption function with the encryptedPass value

```
decryptionFun(encryptedPass);
```

This should return a string and you can use it an decrypted password .

For more information read the [external config docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) .

Comment: thanks for the response. How do I make sure that this decryptionFun is called before Spring Boot configures the datasource.

Comment: sorry , i dont get the comment's question well , can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: Spring boot automatically creates the datasource based on the properties available in application.properties. So by the time, Spring Boot gets to this point the password should have been decrypted. How do I make sure that my decryptionFun gets called before Spring Boot even creates the datasource. My application.properties has the below entries. 1. spring.datasource.url 2. spring.datasource.username 3. spring.datasource.password 4. spring.datasource.driver-class-name

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by creating Datasource programmatically as below:-

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment environment;
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSourceBuilder.url(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSourceBuilder.username("test");//environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.user")
        dataSourceBuilder.password(decryptPassword("encyptedPasswordFromPropertiesFile"));//environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.password")
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Use your custom method to decrypt the password.

```
private String decryptPassword(String encycptedPassword)){
 // Decryption Logic
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much for the response N K Shukla. I tried this but it doesn't work. I get a SQL Exception: invalid username/password; login denied error. I put a sysout in the above getDataSource() function to see if that gets called. It doesn't get called.

Comment: Can you provide the complete code snippet and error logs ?

Comment: This solution should work.  But i truely hope there is a way to decrypt the password, without having to manually create a DataSource bean. Think of this, just for the sake of dealing with the password, i have to go thru the hassle of setting up other properties.    @VLN for now, the best way to avoid the hassle, is to use the jasypt-spring-boot-starter library